# "Naïve" vs "Ignorant"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, word-usage, connotation

What is the difference between *naïve* and *ignorant*? I want to make sure I understand the proper meaning and connotation of each word.

For example, how would you describe a person who makes inappropriate (e.g., discriminatory or offensive) comments about something due to lack of experience or knowledge? Is this person *naïve*, *ignorant*, or both? What connotation does each carry when used to describe the person in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Naive has less of an association of being willfully misinformed. There are many usages e.g. "naive Bayesian", but the appropriate **[definition here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naive)** is:

> 1. marked by unaffected simplicity: artless, ingenuous...  2. deficient in worldly wisdom: credulous

Ignorance can reveal itself when a person unquestioningly sticks to a particular view point, due to an unwillingness or inability to consider alternatives. **[Ignorance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignorance?show=0&t=1329620599)**

> results from or shows lack of knowledge or education; lack of
>   intelligence or awareness

The person described in the question could be both naive and ignorant. Naivete can be due to an unsophisticated world view, or unrealistic outlook from a lack of practical experience. But that doesn't have negative associations. I think ***ignorant*** would be the most well-understood way of describing a person with the attitudes mentioned.

Instead of naive, consider ***provincial***, as that has negative connotations and is better matched with ***ignorant***.

Answer (score 4):

Being "ignorant refers to a lack of **knowledge**. Being "naive" refers to a lack of **understanding**.

An ignorant person (factually) might nevertheless have great understanding and therefore not be naive. Think of the Scarecrow in the Wizard of Oz.

A well-informed (non-ignorant) person might also be naive because s/he doesn't understand things. Maybe the Cowardly Lion is in this category.

Answer (score 2):

Ignorant has a strong negative connotation and means that a person doesn't know things that they should know. Naive has a more neutral connotation and generally indicates a person who isn't familiar with the way the world works. Naive can sometimes even have a positive connotation and mean someone who hasn't been jaded by the negative realities of the world. Naive people are likely to be trusting or unsophisticated.

Essentially, ignorance is a lack of knowledge or education. Naivety is a lack of experience and wisdom.

Someone who makes inappropriate comments would more likely be described as ignorant. Someone who thinks that bad things only happen to bad people would be described as naive.

Comment: In other words, Ignorant people are Ipso Facto, People who Are and Always Will Be Ignorant, whereas Naieve people are merely in need of Some More Time to Grow Up.

Comment: -1; ignorant does not always have a 'strong negative connotation'.  I, for example, am ignorant of the rules of American Football.

Comment: @Jez That you chose to use the word "ignorant" rather than just saying that you don't know them gives that statement, at least to me, a strong negative connotation.

Answer (score 1):

naive is someone who doesn't see the bad in people or in some situations, maybe due to lack of experience but it doesn't mean he s stupid or ignorant. it definitely has nothing to do with ignorance!

Comment: please add some references and/or definitions to inform audiences